# Call commands within docker container

Tags: python, bash, docker

I have a docker container where I need to run some commands. Usually, I do this manually by running the following commands:

```
host> docker exec -it my-container bash
container> eval $(ssh-agent)
container> ssh-add ~/.ssh/my-key
<TYPE PASSPHRASE!!!>
container> pytest
```

I've tried to call `docker exec -it` from the subprocess, but I couldn't mimic the same behavior as the manual workflow. I can't send commands one by one, as the ssh key is loaded only for the current session, if I run it non-interactively I can't use the key.

I have two problems - I need to type passphrase via stdin (I don't see a way to provide it together with `ssh-add`), and I want to know when `pytest` will exit and the return code.

What is the most seamless way to achieve that? I'd prefer to avoid installing additional dependencies, but if it's necessary then I can use something.

Comment: I once read that if you want to ssh into your containers, you are doing something wrong. The whole idea is to have the container run only one process. Be it `pytest` or be it your very application. Can't you simply spawn a new container and wait for it with `docker run my-image pytest`? I don't quite understand what are you trying to work around with the ssh thing.

Comment: Determine what circumstances should trigger these commands. Then make calls to the container to trigger the commands. Or if it is time-related > cronjobs..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ssh-agent listens on a Unix socket; its location is in the `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable.  You can use a Docker bind mount (`docker run -v` option) to inject this socket into the container.  Then when you run `ssh-add` on the host, provided the socket is accessible and the environment variable is set correctly on the host, the container can access the credentials in the agent.

I would not use `docker exec` here.  A container generally runs some single command; say in your case that your container is running a Flask or Django application.  You wouldn't normally "go inside" the Django application while it's running to run its unit tests inside the server.  A separate container and a separate process makes more sense.

The invocation I might use here would look something a little more like:

```sh
eval $(ssh-agent)                           # if not already done on login
ssh-add                                     # if not already done on login
docker run \
  --rm \                                    # delete temporary test container when done
  -v "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/tmp/ssh-auth.sock" \  # mount ssh socket into container
  -e SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-auth.sock \     # set socket location to mounted socket
  -u $(id -u) \                             # run as host user (with permissions on the socket)
  your-image \
  pytest                                    # override command to run in container
```

I would be surprised to see unit tests that actually depended on access to particular ssh credentials; you also may find it easier to restructure your tests to mock service clients that need these credentials, or to run these tests in a Python virtual environment on the host before you build a Docker image at all.

Comment: I've never said that this is for unit tests. But this solution really makes sense and it seem to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found expect (or in the case of python, pexpect) to be very helpful in situations where you are stuck with having to supply user input.  Here's a simple script to execute your example (admittedly, there are additional dependencies):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pexpect
from getpass import getpass

prompt = ">"
child = pexpect.spawn ('docker exec -it my-container bash'))  
child.expect (prompt)
child.sendline ('eval $(ssh-agent)')
child.expect (prompt)
child.sendline ('ssh-add ~/.ssh/my-key')
child.expect ('Enter passphrase for /root/.ssh/my-key:')
password = getpass( prompt="Private Key Password:")
child.sendline (password)
child.expect (prompt)
child.sendline ("pytest")
```

I took the example from https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html and put in your commands.

A note on the prompt.  When I tested the code above, my bash shell in my container had a '$' prompt.  I think that I was lucky that '$' worked for me, since it's basically a valid regex.  Your mileage may vary with the '>' prompt, but you may also want to pay attention to the information regarding CR/LF on the same page mentioned above.

I assume that when you launched the container, you mounted your ~/.ssh directory.  When I launched my container to verify the code above, I added the mount option:  `-v ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh`

Answer (score -1):

You have to run this command instead to avoid typing the password

```
sshpass -p [PASSWORD] ssh [USER]@172.17.0.2
```

Comment: The SSH key is not used for SSH connections. It is required in tests to access an internal API. I can't use the password there.